# intermix command line strings in C

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

This is homework, so I am not looking for a direct answer I am more-so looking for the logic behind this. I do not believe the question is stated very well for novice C devs, and I cannot find any resources to help me out here. I am new to C much more a Java guy so this may seem totally and utterly noobish. The instructions are below

- $ ./mixedupecho HELLO!
- .H/EmLiLxOe!dHuEpLeLcOh!oH
  *
- For this program, you can ignore any command-line arguments beyond the first two (including the program name itself):
- $ ./mixedupecho HELLO! morestuff lalala
- .H/EmLiLxOe!dHuEpLeLcOh!oH
  *
- Notice how "HELLO!" is shorter than "./mixedupecho", and so the program "wraps around"
- and starts over again at 'H'whenever it reaches the end of the string.
  *
- How can you implement that? The modulo % operator is your friend here.
- Spcecifically, note that "HELLO!"[5] yields '!', and "HELLO!"[6] is beyond the bounds of the array.
- But "HELLO!"[6 % 6] evaluates to "HELLO!"[0], which yields 'H'.
- And "HELLO!"[7 % 6] evaluates to "HELLO!"[1] ...

Below is the code I have so far. This iterates through the every character of the argv string which I get. What I don't get is how to print it off so instead of the sequence [0][0], [0][1], [0][2]... I get [0][0], [1][0], [0][1]... etc.

Can someone take a crack at explaining this to me?

```
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
{

    for(int j = 0, n = strlen(argv[i]); j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("%c", argv[i][j]);
        }
}
printf("\n");
```

}

THANKS SO MUCH! THIS IS DRIVING ME INSANE!

Comment: Looks like random spam to me.. Update: Well, no. Just at the first glance. But the guy who have written the description has a total mess in their head.

Comment: "THANKS SO MUCH! THIS IS DRIVING ME INSANE!" - Don't state the obvious. (SCNR)

Comment: I want to know the name of the institution giving such a homework.

Comment: This is the cs50 course sponsored by LaunchCode.

Comment: hint #1:  main should be defined as:  int main(int argc, char **argv);           Hint #2: argv[0] is the name of the program... If you are to only print out the command line arguments, should you include the program's name too?

Comment: @TonyB The `cs50.h` header that is included with every project unfortunately uses `typedef char *string;` so the declaration of `main` is correct.

Comment: @Chrono Kitsune Ugh... sounds like trying to write Java in C... I recall seeing the same with someone creating defines to make C look like Pascal, which they were more familiar with.

Comment: Yes, I want to stay with the course curriculum. So apparently this is possible without using pointers or char *argv []. I've tried creating a function that takes care of it but again, I can't use pointers so I'm not sure how to make that. I've tried every loop I can think of. I'm just lost on it. The exercise before this was simply reversing the string, which was no problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

You want to keep the index `i` incrementing until it is equal to the index of the null terminator in the longest string. Meanwhile, you'll use the `%` operator to ensure that `i` stays within the boundaries of the shorter string.

Here's how I'd do it:

1. Set the initial (unsigned) lengths to `-1U` to avoid calculating lengths unnecessarily. I'll use `LIMIT` for the rest of this example as if I did `#define LIMIT -1U`.
2. Iterate through the strings, checking to ensure that `argv[N][i] % len[N]` is not a null terminator. If it is a null terminator and `len[N] == LIMIT`, set `len[N] = i`.
3. When the expression `len[0] != LIMIT && len[1] != LIMIT` is true, the loop ends since both strings will have the correct length, meaning all characters in each string have been enumerated.

The only thing left is printing the character for each string, which I'm sure you can handle. I would have used `0` as the initial length, except that complicates things since you can't do `x % 0`. The reason for unsigned length is that `-1U` results in an `unsigned int` value (e.g. 4294967295 or 65535); plain `-1` results in `x % -1`, which makes no sense because dividing by -1 yields no remainder.